# How to open .crt file in Android ?

Tags: android, xml, file, layout, x509certificate

Few devices in android unable to read .crt (Certificate File) whereas few can. How to deal with this device related issue ? Is there any other Intent to open file other than ACTION_VIEW which can be an alternative to open file.

```
File vpnCerti = new File("/sdcard/VPNCertificate/Install.crt");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(vpnCerti); //Mime Type Info : http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm
                MimeTypeMap type_map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                //Get the extension from the path
                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path.toString());
                extension = extension.toLowerCase();
                if (extension.contains(".")) {
                    extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("."));
                }
                String mime_type = type_map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Log.d("DownloadManager", "MIME Type : " + mime_type);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vpnCerti), mime_type);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try
                {
                    Log.d("DownloadManager", "Trying to open file");
                    startActivity(i);
                    Log.d("DownloadManager", "Opened file");
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.d("DownloadManager", "Couldn't open file");
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Couldn't find specific activity to open it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact problem you are encountering right now (without the stack trace it is very hard to tell), but it may be because some of your devices don't have a SD card installed. In fact, I have been researching for the best solution to load a certificate, and if you only have a few certificates to manage, putting them in /res/raw/ folder might be a better idea than storing them in sd card. Here is how to load one from /res/raw/:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert_id);
```